# Запуск двух и более php-скриптов асинхронно внутри php-скрипта

Tags: php

Уважаемые коллеги, мне хотелось бы написать один единственный скрипт, который я вставил бы в кронтаб на хостинге. А внутри его было бы что-то типа

```
<?php
exec(file1.php);
exec(file2.php);
....
?>
```

И чтобы не было ожидания при переходе от одного вызова exec к другому. Спасибо!

Comment: В очереди поставить их исполнение?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Ставить задачи в очереди, и пусть очереди сами отработают эти файлы

Comment: В очередь - вы о кронтабе говорите? Желательно это сделать именно так, как я описал - хотелось бы этой системой в админке сайта управлять, а не на хостинге.

Comment: Можно и на кроне очереди сделать, но я бы наверное делал на каком-нибудь редисе или раббите

Comment: Ну а ссылками или идеями вы поделиться можете? В какую сторону копать хотя бы.

Comment: Можно же и погуглить иногда https://coderun.ru/blog/ehmulyaciya-ocheredejj-pri-pomoshhi-cron-na-wordpress-sajjte/

Comment: С такой помощью, придется таки.... Спасибо большое!